# How to make a dockerfile with piwigo and a database

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I wanna to create a dockerfile with piwigo and any database, but I don't know how to start. I tried to use docker-compose up and it works, but I really want to just to make the command

```
 docker build and docker run
```

I tried to docker build and run from this repo https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-piwigo
and it doesnt work